# Одушевленный "источник"

Tags: словоупотребление, одушевлённость

Как правильно употреблять (и как обычно употребляется) слово "источник" во фразах вроде *пишет Bloomberg со ссылкой на 2 источник..., знаком... с ситуацией*?

С одной стороны, в этом случае разговор идет о людях, имеющих доступ к какой-то информации, поэтому логично предположить, что слово "источник" здесь одушевленное и что правильно использовать окончание род. падежа: *со ссылкой на двух источников*.

С другой стороны, такое употребление режет слух (возможно, только мне), и по словарям я себя проверить не могу, т.к. на Академике и на Грамоте не указана одушевленность слов.

Меня интересует 3 вопроса:

1. Как правильно говорить, и регулируется ли это употребление где-либо?
2. Как обычно говорят?
3. Есть ли еще какие-нибудь случаи, когда слово "источник" употребляется как одушевленное (окончание родительного падежа в контексте винительного)?

Comment: "Со ссылкой на двух источников" - определённо режет слух. По моему мнению, когда ссылаются на источник, то имеют ввиду человека не как персону, а как автора публикации, книги, интервью, репортажа... . Использование выражения "ссылка на источник" как раз имеет целью обезличить автора, на которого ссылаются. То есть "источник" в данном случае - это не человек, а текст/аудио/видео, автором которого он является.

Answer (score 3):

Со ссылкой на два источника.
Неодушевлённое слово и есть неодушевлённое. Так звучит правильно.

"В то же время имена существительные неодушевленные при употреблении их в переносном значении категорию неодушевленности не сохраняют и при склонении изменяются как существительные одушевленные.

Например: Призовите к порядку этого типа; Уговори поехать с нами за город этого старого колпака; В иного пня и десять лет не вдолбить того, что другой ловит на полете (Фонвизин)". (Валгина, Розенталь, Фомина, глава 114.)

В данном случае, всё-таки, переносный смысл сомнителен, поскольку речь идёт об "источнике информации", пусть и одушевлённом.

Comment: А есть ли примеры к цитате?

Comment: Примеры употребления фразы «со ссылкой на два источника»: 
1) http://lenta.ru/news/2012/11/19/rosatom/
2) http://www.newsru.com/russia/05dec2012/voronova.html
3) http://www.itar-tass.com/c11/602075.html

Comment: Я хотела спросить, есть ли примеры из (Валгина, Розенталь, Фомина), которые относятся к цитате.

Comment: @Olga - Розенталь цитирует "Героев нашего времени" Лермонтова: "... ты любил меня как собственность, как **источник** радостей, тревог и печалей". user952 прав.

Comment: @YellowSky Then his citation does not support his claim.

Comment: @Olga - В том-то и дело, что и у Лермонтова, и в вашем случае ("источник информации") значение слова прямое, а не переносное, поэтому надо употреблять это слово как неодушевлённое. Ведь вы же не станете утверждать, что у Лермонтова и слово "собственность" тоже в переносном значении употребляется?

Comment: @YellowSky Переместимся в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3764/russian-language-and-usage

Comment: Иллюстрация к цитате из Розенталя.
"Например: Призовите к порядку этого _типа_; Уговори поехать с нами за город этого старого _колпака_; В иного _пня_ и десять лет не вдолбить того, что другой ловит на полете (Фонвизин)."

Но это про переносный смысл. А "источник" здесь имеет прямой смысл как источник информации.

Comment: Спасибо за примеры! Так намного понятнее, что за примеры авторы справочника имеют в виду.